# THREAD WARNING: ['Keyboard'] took '88.104980' ms. Plugin should use a background thread

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-keyboard

i am using phonegap build for creating ipa with ionic html framework and using latest cli like
`<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-6.5.0" />`
and ionic keyboard using latest version
`<plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" source="npm" version="2.2.1" />`

Now after uploading latest ipa to itune it never shows keyboard very first click
and i see log like

`<Warning>: THREAD WARNING: ['Keyboard'] took '58.110840' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.`

Any one please help me to solve out this big issue as keyboard always shows after second click into input box or textarea even now it also not open select drop down very first time click

See issue url
http://prntscr.com/emkaxz

Thank you in advance